# How and when to bind a function to a dynamic html content in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, uikit

I have a component where I have to bind a function to every div which are dynamic. I have used UIkit sortable component group, where on drag and drop to a specific div it executes the specific code bound to it.

For example: I have a `div`

```
<div id="abc"></div>
```

and we have to bind a function to it like this:

```
UIkit.util.on("abc", "added", (item)=>{
  //Do something
})
```

In my case I have dynamic contents. The `div` are rendered using `*ngFor`
and functions are bounded to them by using `.map` function.

To bind the function the html content should be loaded to the DOM. But the function is called before the DOM gets loaded with the dynamic content. So the functions are not getting bound.
I called the function in `ngAfterViewInit` still its not helping.

The following is my code:

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let batch of batches">
    <div [attr.id]="batch.batchId" uk-sortable="group: sortable-group">
        <div *ngFor="let stud of batch.students">
            <div [attr.id]="stud.id" class="uk-margin">
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">Item 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit=()=>{
   this.getBatch().then(batch=>{
      this.batches = batch
   });
}

ngAfterViewInit=()=>{
    this.initializeDragChange();
}

initializeDragChange = () => {
  this.batches.map((item) => {
    UIkit.util.on(`${item.batchId}`, "added", (item) => {
       //do something
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I think it's not recommended to manipulate DOM dynamically via angular, it will affect your application performance , why you didn't think of another idea for your use case and functional need implementation

Comment: Yes, there are some different approaches to my problem. But I wanted to know how can I solve it using this way

Comment: do you want to use click event for example to be bonded to your div element ?